# Polymorphic relation to itself too in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, hierarchical-data, polymorphic-associations

I'm using Symfony 3.0.1 (doctrine/orm ^2.5) and I want to have a polymorphic relation on Forum entity to Category or Forum entities (as in the image). You can imagine it like a simple forum website example. You have got general category -> forum -> subforum -> subsubforum etc. What's the best way to do that?

[image: Polymorphic relation to itself]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at nested sets in the doctrine extension. I've used them and found them very easy - they take care of a lot of the complications involved in handling nested set relationships. In your case `Forum` would be be just annotated with `@Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")`. Each forum would have a ManyToOne relation to `Category` as well as a relation to its own parent forum.

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md